# How to create a custom UIView that defines a baseline?

Tags: uiview, autolayout

Using the `NSLayoutConstraint` class, it is possible to create a constraint that is based on a view's baseline (`NSLayoutAttributeBaseline`). However, I haven't seen any documentation that describes how a `UIView` actually provides a baseline value to the auto layout system.

If I wanted to create a custom `UIView` subclass that defines a baseline, how would I do it? `NSView` defines a `baselineOffsetFromBottom` method that I assume is involved somehow on OS X, but how does this work in iOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the UIView docs:

> `viewForBaselineLayout`
>
> Returns a view used to satisfy baseline constraints.
>
> `- (UIView *)viewForBaselineLayout`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The view the constraint system should use to satisfy baseline constraints

Answer (score 9):

I've just used Hopper disassembler to look at UILabel in iOS 8.1, and it implements methods `_baselineOffsetFromBottom` and `_firstBaselineOffsetFromTop`, which are in turn called by `-[UIView nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:]`, so UIKit has private methods similar to the one OS X has, they are just not exposed to the public.

`_baselineOffsetFromBottom` and `_firstBaselineOffsetFromTop` are implemented by UIView (returning 0), UILabel and UITextView. There's also a class named `_UIGlintyStringView` that implements `_baselineOffsetFromBottom`; no other UIKit classes have these methods.

Btw when the baseline of a view changes, it performs something like:

```
__UITagLayoutConstraintsForConstantChangeForSelectedAttributes(self, __UILayoutAttributeIsBaselineAttribute)
```

Doesn't seem like there's anything extra-special that couldn't be exposed to the public; perhaps they didn't feel like there's a need or wanted to discourage people from writing their own labels. UILabel is a fairly complicated class involving a custom CoreAnimation layer (_UILabelLayer) and a whole lot of trickery, including quite a bit of code for accessibility support.

Comment: That's a great find. It's really unfortunate that these methods aren't public. Maybe I will submit a feature request to make them public.

Answer (score 2):

You can also override one of the baseline values, i.e. `firstBaselineOffsetFromTop`, if aligning to a view is not convenient. For example, here's code that sets the first baseline to halfway down the view:

```
override var firstBaselineOffsetFromTop: CGFloat {
    return bounds.midY
}
```

EDIT: My bad, that's MacOS. I believe the iOS equivalent is `firstBaselineAnchor` which returns an `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` object. I've not tested this, but I expect this would have a similar effect:

```
override var firstBaselineAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return NSLayoutYAxisAnchor.anchorWithOffset(bounds.midY)
}
```

Comment: That might work. As I recall, anchors didn't exist when I originally asked the question.

Comment: Yep, introduced in iOS9, which was late 2015.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to create an arbitrary NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, be it based on an offset or anything else. The sample iOS code above doesn't compile. Seems that on iOS we're suck with returning an existing anchor here.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a real oversight, that. Funny, I'm sure I managed it in a previous OS version.

Comment: This does not work. One case override firstBaselineAnchor and make it return `centerYAnchor` for instance, but iOS seems to ignore it (even though the override _is_ called).

Answer (score 2):

```
viewForBaselineLayout
```

is deprecated so you have to use

```
viewForFirstBaselineLayout
```

example

```
- (UIView *)viewForFirstBaselineLayout  {
    // Use subLabel view for handling baseline layouts
    return self.subLabel;
}
```